# Argparse in Jupyter Notebook throws a TypeError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, argparse

Using argparse in a Jupyter Notebook throws a TypeError. The same code works fine if I execute the same code as a script. MWE:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Foo')
parser.add_argument('--name', '-n', default='foo', help='foo')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Result:

```
TypeError: 'level' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: Show the full traceback.  That code is not producing this error.

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to parse an empty list of arguments:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Foo')
parser.add_argument('--name', '-n', default='foo', help='foo')

args = parser.parse_args([])
```

Another is to use parse_known_args:

```
args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
```

Comment: Cool! Simple and nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

Ipython is running some command-line arguments in the background. This interfers with argparse and optparse.

See [this bug for Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3883) (Ipython IDE), where `-f` was being added as a command option and crashing as there was no handler for `-f`.

You could try checking the arguments currently in play (as they did for the Spyder bug) and putting a dummy handler in place.

Run

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

inside Ipython and see what it outputs.

On my system, it gives

> ['/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py', '-f', '/run/user/1000/jupyter/kernel-7537e4dd-b5e2-407c-9d4c-7023575cfc7c.json']

[Argparse assumes the first entry is the program name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prog) (`sys.argv[0]`). In order to fix this, I had to call

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='myprogram', description='Foo')
```

... and now `argparse` works in my notebook.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, the import does not work for me (ModuleNotFound).

Comment: Looks like Ipython has the option of including a set of pip modules (like argparse) which you can use without them being system-installed. These they call the external modules. If you have a standard system install of argparse, ignore the external ref. The first point still stands though - you need to follow what the Spyder team did. Run print(sys.argv), find out what is missing, add a dummy handler.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code in a Notebook, I get an `argparse` usage error message:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--name NAME]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /run/user/1000/jupyter/kernel-a6504c0c-bed2-4405-8704-c008f52dcba6.json
```

With a `print(sys.argv)` I get

```
['/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py', '-f', '/run/user/1000/jupyter/kernel-a6504c0c-bed2-4405-8704-c008f52dcba6.json']
```

`sys.argv`, which `parser` parses, contains the values used to launch the Notebook server, which this particular `parser` is not setup to handle.

`parser.parse_known_args()` displays:

```
(Namespace(name='foo'),
 ['-f',
  '/run/user/1000/jupyter/kernel-a6504c0c-bed2-4405-8704-c008f52dcba6.json'])
```

That extra stuff that your parser can't handle is put in the `extras` list.

Run with a custom `argv` list works:

```
parser.parse_args(['-n', 'foobar'])
Namespace(name='foobar')
```

---

It's a good idea to put `argparse` code (at least the `parse_args` line) in a `__main__` block, so it is not run when the script is imported. It will still run when the script is run as a script.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Foo')
    parser.add_argument('--name', '-n', default='foo', help='foo')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

This script also works when using `%run stack50763033.py`.  You can even give it arguments as you would with a script:

```
%run stack50763033.py -n testing
```

---

I have no idea what code is producing the `level` keyword error.  You'll have to give us the traceback if you want help with that.